# How to filter from a list of countries in django-countries

Tags: python, django, django-countries

In my project, i am using CountryField of django countries inside one of my models. Also, all the countries are displaying in the particular field named 'country'. But what i want is that i have to filter some countries from the list of total countries(one more issue here is that if all the countries are showing, then my template design will remain in conflict. So can anybody help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As Doc suggests . you can use `COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE` dict in settings . you can set particular countries to `None` if you want to exclude those countries from your list. Like:

```
COUNTRIES_OVERRIDE = {
    'NZ': _('Middle Earth'),
    'AU': None
}
```

Comment: yes. Its only way . As far as i know , you can't exclude countries with criteria like `Seven Continents` or by `oceans` using `django-countries` . For such case you have to make your own country list. :)